# Automatic connect wordpress to facebook with featured image?

Tags: facebook, featured-post

I want, when I publish any post, that it shows my facebook with featured image. Most of the plugins don't show feature images but shows other images.

How can I do it - simply connect to facebook and add link to facebook. I have already used a sample connect facebook plugin but it's not publishing automatically.

I'm also using it on `dlvr.it` and `twitterfeed.com`. It posts automatically but don't show featured images. It shows the previous post featured image.

How I can solve this problem. My [site](http://www.desyfun.tk)

Comment: What have you tried already? Please show us some code, and describe what you want with more details. And _please,_ write readable English; it is very hard for a non-native speaker to read your question.

Comment: I think the OP is saying they are using @Otto Simple Facebook Connect plugin. But the posts dont publish automatically to Facebook. They also use dlvr.it and twitterfeed.com but the RSS feed doesn't include  the featured image.

Comment: exactly i want to say it....@Damien

Comment: which code you want to see? @toscho

Comment: @SmartShovon There are maybe dedicated hooks in the plugins you are using or you could have written an attempt to solve the problem. It is always better to see what you have tried and what didn’t work.

Comment: any problem in my theme Html code? can you tell it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Facebook plugin. I recommend you change the plugin to the official [Facebook plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/)  - it's been made by some of the same people and allows you to publish immediately.

Image in your RSS feed:
Your RSS feed should be found [here](http://www.desyfun.tk/feed) (but it's not there?) because you are using another RSS feed plugin.

Your RSS Feed is [here](http://www.desyfun.tk/?feed=rss), so check if your RSS plugin has a setting to include image.

You might try a plugin like this [Featured Image In RSS Feed](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/featured-image-in-rss-feed/) as well

Also if it is showing an old image, check if you do not have a website cache plugin as that may be caching old content.

Comment: not working it.